# I am trying to use javascript scrollheight and jQuery scrollTop() but not getting any result

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, scrolltop, console.log

This is the code I am using in my console.

```
var h = jQuery(this).scrollHeight; 


console.log(h);
```

This is showing "undefined" in the console.

```
jQuery("#activeslide3 p").scroll(function(){    
var pos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();    
console.log(pos);
});
```

This is not giving any output on scroll.

Comment: **jQuery(this)** gives the reference to window which has no scrollHeight property hence giving "undefined".

Comment: give a value inside scrolltop..something like jQuery(this).scrollTop(300)

Comment: Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8527/) the sort of thing you are after?